# How to fake domain in address bar (to show completely different domain)?

Tags: dns

Is there a way that I for example use my website called `www.mywebsite.com` and in address bar to show `www.wikipedia.com`?

And of course to load my contents from `mywebsite.com`?

Comment: Do you have managerial access to the _fake_ address?

Comment: Why would you want to do that if not for malicious phising purposes?

Comment: I want to fake my partner for something..so i want to make a website and when he goes there he will think he is on different website..long story short is there a way for this ?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the kind of thing that you don't want to happen, because then, many people would fish visitors going to facebook.com into their ads or clickbait websites instead. You couldn't do it even if you wanted to, it would be like saying, if you call at Person A's number, it would directly refer to Person B instead.

Hope that gives you an explaination!

Comment: Bad example. Google for **call forwarding**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe to display the contents from Wikipedia or any other URL on your webpage.

Comment: No..i want the opposite..i want to display my content on my website, but visitors to see wikipedia.com instead of my url

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible and its illegal too. 
I have a way you can use, but I'm not sure if that's gonna work.
When a user visits your site, you may automatically fullscreen the browser and display a layout according to what browser the user is using and display the content inside the fake browser layoout. But my idea is just lame because user is easily gonna find out that's fake.